# How to get facebook groups (not pages) feed (posts' title+content)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've seen many posts around most of them are about pages or with outdated information.

I need to collect the feed (let's say last 10 posts: title + content) of 2 different Facebook groups in real-time (or almost) possibly in JSON in order to get real-time notifications about new posts (e.g. via kimonolabs service, but any other solution is accepted).

How do to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no realtime updates for groups. You would need to get the feed on your own - with a Cron Job, for example.

Be aware that you can only get access to groups you manage, with the `user_managed_groups` permission and the `/group-id/feed` endpoint.

Check out the API reference for example code and all the information you need: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/group

Comment: thank you. so no way to get a simple feed from groups I follow (but not own) just for my personal use?

Comment: nope, not anymore. the user_groups permission is deprecated: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4